# facebook app requests and redirect

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the code below have people invite their friends to my app. However, i want to redirect the user to a webpage with content rather than a useless array of IDs  after the invitations are sent. Second, when the recipient gets the invite and clicks how do I redirect him to my other page instead of yet another array of Ids?

What I did was paste this code in my www.domain.com/fir/index.php file with the correct app ID and canvas.

```
 <?php 

             $app_id = "546546545456";

             $canvas_page = "http://domain.com/dir/";

             $message = "Would you like to join me in this great app?";

             $requests_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=" 
                    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)
                    . "&message=" . $message;

             if (empty($_REQUEST["request_ids"])) {
                echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $requests_url . "'</script>");
             } else {
                echo "Request Ids: ";
                print_r($_REQUEST["request_ids"]);
             }
    ?>
```

Comment: why do u need to print request ids?

Comment: can you please be a bit more clear with your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the array of IDs printed, don't print them. You can use php to redirect instead of echoing out javascript, try

```
<?php header('Location: http://google.com') ?>
```